# Get cropped Image on server side in mvc and jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to crop image before uploading it to server. But on server side, I'm getting the actual size of image not the cropped image.
this is my code.

I'm using this [**plugin**](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/)

```
<input type="button" id="btnCroped" value="Crop and Upload" />
```

JS

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ImgaeCropper/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ImgaeCropper/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="~/Content/ImgaeCropper/cropper.js"></script>

<script src="~/Content/ImgaeCropper/main.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#FileUpload1').change(function () {
            $('#Image1').hide();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#Image1').show();
                $('#Image1').attr("src", e.target.result);
                $('.container > img').cropper({
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    autoCropArea: 0.65,
                    strict: false,
                    guides: false,
                    highlight: false,
                    dragCrop: false,
                    cropBoxMovable: true,
                    cropBoxResizable: false
                });
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
        });

        $('#btnCroped').on('click', function () {
            debugger;
            $('.container > img').cropper('crop');
            $('.container > img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
                var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Upl',
                    method: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('Upload success');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('Upload error');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upl()
        {

            HttpPostedFileBase newImage = Request.Files["croppedImage"];
            var folder =System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");

            if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
            }
            var getExt = Path.GetExtension(newImage.FileName).ToLower();
            var picName = Guid.NewGuid() + newImage.FileName;
            newImage.SaveAs(folder + picName);

            return View();
        }
```

I followed this [code](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/README.md#getcroppedcanvasoptions)

Comment: What's the Debuggers Output for formData?

Comment: Take some F12 Tools and place a breakpoint...

Comment: I got that. blob is `Blob { size=160111,  type="image/png",  slice=slice()}`
and this append to formdata.
[See this code](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/master/README.md#getcroppedcanvasoptions)

Comment: so any luck on it, if so it will be great if you share your solution.?